# Highlight the distance between two points in an image and find the max distance using python opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am pretty new to using opencv, and i want to know how can find the distance of this max gap(the highlighted red triangle region). I was thinking of finding the edge first but not sure how to calculate the distance. Like the image i attached, i want to first highlight the portion and then find the max distance(purple line drawn on the last image). The output should be the image with highlight and calculated distance output.

[image]

Comment: check "convexity defects": https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html

Comment: @Miki *please* do not link to the `tutroals` site. it is the outdated version of current OpenCV documentation. ALL of that information is on docs.opencv.org: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it's just a comment and I put the first google hit. For an answer (that I'm not going to make) I would have spent a minute to find a "better" link. Thanks for the link anyway ;)